# algorithm to select any point in Europe and see the distance from that point to any major city in Europe

Tags: algorithm

Is there an algorithm to select **any point in Europe** and see the distance from that point to any major city in  Europe (maybe up to 10 cities)?

Comment: distance in a straight line?  distance along roads?  If straight its a sipmle calculation based on longitute and latitute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)